# Cohomological dimension of torsion-free groups and its subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, cohomology, group-cohomology, projective-resolution

In [this thesis](http://theses.gla.ac.uk/182/) by Martin Hamilton on
Finiteness Conditions in Group Cohomology there is on page 11 a reference to following result:

**Theorem 1.2.14.** If $G$ is a *torsion-free* group and $H$ is a
subgroup of *finite index*, then

$$ \operatorname{cd} H = \operatorname{cd} G  $$

where $\operatorname{cd} G $ is the cohomological dimension of $G$
defined as the **projective dimension**
of $\mathbb{Z}$ considered as $\mathbb{Z}G$-module with
trivial $G$ action, i.e. $g.1=1$ for every $g \in G$.

That is $\operatorname{cd} G = 
\operatorname{proj.dim}_{\mathbb{Z}G} \mathbb{Z}$ and
the latter is defined as the minimal length of all projecive
resolutions

$$ 0 \to P_n \to P_{n-1} \to ... \to P_1 \to P_0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0 $$

of projective $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules $P_j$.

In the thesis the author gave as reference
Jean-Pierre Serre's publication "Cohomologie des groupes discrets", can be found in this Bourbaki collection band:
https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540057208

Unfortunatelly, this result cannot be found in this publication. So my concern
is where I can find a complete proof of the quoted Theorem above.

Comment: The reference in the thesis is not to that "Cohomologie des groupes discrets" by Serre. It's to another "Cohomologie des groupes discrets" by Serre (there seem to be at least three).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is Theorem 3.1, p. 190, in Brown, "Cohomology of groups". He also attributes it to Serre.

As a remark, this is the reason that the virtual cohomological dimension (vcd) is well-defined.